# Read/Parse XML file in Cmake build CmakeList.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, xml-parsing

I want to parse eclipse ProjectInfo.xml file in Cmake to get some configuration information.

How to parse or read XML file in Cmake build script?

Comment: You might try XSLT scripting.

Answer (score 0):

CMake has no native support for XML parsing.

You may use (with `execute_process` command) any existed tool which will parse XML and creates CMake script with needed variable's set. Then you may include resulted script with `include` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) or any other command line XML parser via an [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html).